# Elastic Search Java API Multi match query prefix query on tokens

Tags: search, elasticsearch, n-gram

I am looking for some way that I want to perform search on my index with NativeSearchQueryBuilder from Elastic java api but I want to add the following things while search.
Index details:

1. Filter type EdgeNgram
2. White space tokenizer

I am looking for autocomplete functionality so here i want to apply the search keyword on multiple fields but it should apply using prefix to improve the performance, also I want to the results needs to be returned if they reach my specified page limit instead of keep on searching the index even it found enough results.

Ex: "albert einstein" is there in my index, now if I search "alb" it should return the result or if I search "ein" it should return the result.

```
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder sb = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withIndices(Constants.ES_INDEX_NAME)
            //.withPageable(pageable)
            .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilterBuilder().withIncludes("id").build())
            .withTypes(Constants.USERS_TYPE)
            .withQuery(multiMatchQuery("alb", new String[]{"userFirstName","userLastName","userMobile", "userEmail"}))
            .withFilter(boolQuery()
                    .must(termQuery("userCityName", "Chicago")));
```

Please someone help me on this, how to add prefix and limit to my Multimatch Query builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `match_phrase_prefix`

```
int limit = 100; //Set your limit

NativeSearchQueryBuilder sb = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withIndices(Constants.ES_INDEX_NAME)
            .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, limit))
            .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilterBuilder().withIncludes("id").build())
            .withTypes(Constants.USERS_TYPE)
            .withQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("alb", "userFirstName","userLastName","userMobile", "userEmail")
                                    .type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX))
            .withFilter(boolQuery()
                    .must(termQuery("userCityName", "Chicago")));
```

Comment: Thanks it is working but i wonder this prefix query will improve the performance or it degrades it, actually my index is having 80k records but it is taking on avg 400ms for retrieving the results, does it looks good or still can improve the performace, I am using EdgeNGram with empty space tokenizer min 3 and max 20 letters .

Comment: Any `phrase` or `prefix` will degrade the search performance. You need to understand the operations happening behind the scenes, phrase or prefix match will look for the tokens, then check for order and then assign a score which will take more time than any regular match but with ES's performance you will not feel the difference most of the time. 400 ms for 80k documents seems bit on the higher side but it depends on your document size and ES sizing.

Comment: Generally what will be the number for optimum level of performance for 80K documents with average of 1kb.

Comment: I can't comment exactly for 80k documents but for my case with 1 billion + documents with average doc size of 150kb, a regular match phrase with 2 to 3 words usually takes somewhere between 100ms to 150ms.